# JFrames/Objects access between two different projects

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I have two separate projects, A and B, added the jar file of B in A's Libraries using netbeans. A has two JFrame (BasicFrame1 and BasicFrame2) and B has JFrame (Newframe). When i tries to make visible BsicFrame2 and unvisible BasicFrame1 it all works coz they are in the same project. But whenever i tries to make visible the project B's JFrame (Newframe) by clicking on the button in Project A's BasicFrame1 it does not show anything.

```
Newframe connenct=new Newframe();
this.BasicFrame1.setVisible(false);
Newframe.setVisible(true);
```

Please help me, why this not working and the same case when i try to access the Newframe's jPanel (butPanel).

```
Newframe connect=new Newframe();
    connect.butPanel.setVisible(true);
```

This code also does not works but when i do this between the project A's Frames it works. What's the mistake i have done? Please help.

Comment: There's a good chance the second one isn't working because you've misspelt 'connect'

Comment: @Tharwen Sorry this spell mistake wasn't in the real code.

Comment: Your call to setVisible looks like a static call: this looks like a poor design choice. You should probably post the code of Newframe to see what's going on.

Comment: Have you set the size and location of newFrame??